# tsconfig Path Alias options

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm using typescript in my Next.js project, and I have a file structure like this:

```
|-- tsconfig.json
|-- components/
|---- Footer/
|------ Footer.tsx
|------ Footer.module.sass
```

And my Path Aliases are written like this:

```
    "paths": {
      "@components/*": ["components/*"]
      .
      .
      .
    }
```

So whenever I need to import a component, like my Footer for example, I can write

```
import { Footer } from '@components/Footer/Footer'
```

This works, but given my file structure, this seems redundant. Since the component name will always be the same as the folder that holds it, would there be a way to keep the same file structure, but have an Alias like

```
import { Footer } from '@components/Footer'
```

I imagine importing all the components into a components file, then exporting them is a solution, but id much rather keep the structure I have going on now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the file name from `Footer.tsx` to `index.tsx`.